# window.load function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I got a small problem with the JavaScript window on load function. The goal of the script is to make the height of my #headerdiv always equal to the size of the screen.

When I open the page it doesn't show my `#headerdiv` (I guess because the height isn't added by my JavaScript code). as soon as I resize my browser window the #headerdiv pups up and resizes to the height of the screen. So I guess its just the window load function which doesn't work? Anyone has a suggestion?

Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
        $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))  +'px'});
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
        $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+ 'px'});
    });
});     
</script>
```

**Html + css:**

```
<style>
    #headerdiv {width:100%; background:blue;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:auto;}​
</style>

<div id="headerdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Would this also not work? `$(window).resize(function(){ 
    $('#headerdiv').height($(this).height())});
   });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need there `$( window ).load()` as `$(function(){` already do `$( document ).ready()` (see official [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for shortcuts)

So at this point your code already loaded. Just try:

```
$(function(){

   $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))  +'px'});

   $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
    $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+ 'px'});
   });

});
```

Comment: Haha, I'm dumb.. Thanx for the fast reply. job fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you need to wait for all images to load, use either:

```
$(window).load(function(){ // On load
  $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))  +'px'});
});

$(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
      $('#headerdiv').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+ 'px'});
   });
});
```

or the answer given by @antyrat. You shouldn't wrap the `$(window).load` in a `$(function()`

Answer (score 0):

I would expand on [antyrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13876621/561731) like so:
(there is no need to repeat code):

```
$(function(){

   $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
       $('#headerdiv').css({'height':  $(window).height() + 'px'});
   }).trigger('resize'); //do the resize function on start

});
```